# An error to create two dimension vector.

Tags: c++, vector, g++

I created a class called `Rect`. And I want to create a vector which accommodates the addresses of `vector<Rect>`, the pointer to `vector<Rect>`.

Here is my code:

```
std::vector< std::vector<Rect> *> *graph;

    for(int i=0 ; i < 8; i++)
    {
            std::vector<Rect> *vecPtr= new std::vector<Rect>;
            graph->push_back( vecPtr ); 
    }
```

However, g++ complains that "Core Dumped".

1. What's the fault about my understanding and why?
2. How can I fix it? The correct code?

Comment: Don't use `*` with `vector`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avoid pointers whenever you can, and this is clearly a good case:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Rect> > graph(8);
```

That single line is (almost, conceptually?) equivalent to your code, does not leak memory and won't *core dump* on you.

As of your particular problem, you never allocated memory for the vector of vectors, `graph`, but you attempted to access it in `graph->push_back(vecPtr)`.

Comment: But I what I want to store is only the address of the vector. It can save spaces. And why pointers causes `core dump`?

Comment: @Stallman: *It can save spaces*. No it can't, how would it? If anything it needs more memory. The pointer does not core dump, dereferencing a pointer that does not point to a valid object does.

Comment: @Stallman You still need to store the vector somewhere, so you're actually wasting one pointer per vector.

Comment: @DavidRodriguez-dribeas  But I don't dereferencing any pointer yet.
Why `Core dumped`?

Comment: @Stallman did you even read the answer? "As of your particular problem, you never allocated memory for the vector of vectors, graph, **but you attempted to access it** in graph->push_back(vecPtr)."

Comment: @DavidRodriguez-dribeas So if I initialize the graph ptr to 0, then I fix the error?

Comment: @Stallman: No, you will just get the same crash really. You need to make the pointer refer to a real object by, for example, `new`-ing a new `vector<vector<Rect>*>` (or remove the pointers altogether!)

Comment: @Stallman Have you even read the answers? Also, you seem to lack a basic understanding of pointers. May I suggest that you read [this](http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~pdiloren/C++_Pointers/).

Comment: Well, I should malloc some memory for the variable `graph` if it's a pointer. Otherwise, it can't accommodate any variables?
And as your answer `graph(8)`, it's already allocate spaces.
Is that right?

Comment: But the outer vector will grow. I don't really know `std::vector<std::vector<Rect> > graph;` will work or not?

Comment: @Stallman: You should **`new`** an object (avoid `malloc`) if it is a pointer. Otherwise there is no object and a no-object cannot accomodate *anything*. The line of code above creates a vector of vectors of `Rect`, initialized with 8 empty vectors (`graph.size() == 8; graph[x].size() == 0` for `0 <= x < 8`). You can still grow both the outer and inner vectors as needed.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas   Ok, I got it. But why can't I just declare `std::vector<std::vector<Rect> > graph`? Isn't it a default constructor for vector? By the way, why should I avoid malloc? Thank you. The declaration is also suggested by @pmr. PLEASE answer me, thank you very much~

Comment: @Stallman: You can do that, but if you want 8 elements you will then need to either call `resize(8)` or otherwise add 8 elements. There is no point in not doing that in the initialization. Less code, less room for errors.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Ok, then why avoiding `malloc`? And I really wan to use `*graph`.

Comment: @Stallman: Regarding `malloc`, it only allocates memory, then you need to construct the object in place. Finally you need to remember to manually destroy the object before you call `free`. `void *ptr = static_cast<T*>(malloc(sizeof(T))); T *p = new (ptr) T; ... ; p->~T(); free(p)` is better spelled: `T *p = new T; ...; delete p;`

Answer (score 2):

Your outermost vector is not initialized. You are effectively calling `push_back` on nothing.

```
std::vector< std::vector<Rect> *> *graph 
  = new std::vector< std::vector<Rect> *>();
```

This will solve your immediate problem, but I really recommend to not manually allocate things. You can also use:

```
std::vector< std::vector<Rect> > graph;
graph.push_back( std::vector<Rect>() );
```

Although a lot of programmers will object to `vector of vector` as having truly awful performance (especially in C++98).

Comment: vector of vector performance in C++03 might not be bad. I know of at least 2 implementations (Dinkumware, BSL) in which it will perform as well as C++11 (it will semantically move, even if the language does not have rvalue references). It also depends on whether the outer vector ever grows, and/or whether you really need this to implement a *jagged array*.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Ah, I didn't know any implementation would do that. Valid point for the jagged arrays.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas  Well, then what's the best for the declaration of the two-dimension vector? Can u give ur answer in ur post? It's question 2. I think this will make your answer more compacyt.

Comment: @pmr: Conceptually it is simple, if `vector` knows of `vector` (which it surely does), when growing it can create the new buffer, default initialize the elements in the new buffer (cheap enough operation, as that does not allocate) and then `swap` (guaranteed to work, cheap --3 pointer swaps, plus optionally the allocator). That can be extended to any other container, even lists (in both implementations, but that is just casuality, the default list constructor allocates) benefit from this approach.

Comment: @pmr: In the case of BSL, it is a bit more efficient and borderline undefined behavior, it just *moves* the objects by doing a bitwise copy and dropping the original buffer. While this is undefined behavior by the standard, the ABI in the supported platforms places additional constraints on what the compiler can do that cause that *standard undefined behavior* into expected behavior in the implementation.

Comment: @Stallman: Do you need a *jagged array*? (i.e. can the internal elements be of different `size()`?) If so, my answer already has the solution: `std::vector<std::vector<Rect> > graph(8);` I assume that to be the case since you are calling it `graph` (not all nodes will have the same amount of outgoing edges?)

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas  Ya, I do need jagged array.

Comment: @pmr Right, If I manually malloc spaces, it will cause trouble as I need to delete them.

Answer (score 1):

graph is a pointer to a `std::vector< std::vector<Rect> *>`. Where do you initialize it? What is its value?

```
std::vector< std::vector<Rect> *> *graph;

graph->... // This is undefined behaviour
```

Always initialize your variables. For example:

```
std::vector< std::vector<Rect> *> *graph = NULL;
```

This is better than your code because at least you *know* that graph does not currently point to an actual `std::vector< std::vector<Rect> *>` object. It is NULL. Pointers must always be either NULL or assigned to addresses of objects of their type.

Construct a `std::vector< std::vector<Rect> *>` and then initialize graph with its address, if you need to use pointers at all. For example:

```
std::vector< std::vector<Rect> *> someObject = new std::vector< std::vector<Rect> *>;
graph = &someObject;
```

Now you could use `graph->`.

In any case, most likely you don't need to use pointers at all in this case so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21335036/96780) is correct.

Comment: Don't use `NULL`, use `nullptr` if your compiler allows it (C++11) or else `0` (well, `NULL` vs. `0` is not that much of a difference more of a preference, but if you have `nullptr`... by all means use it)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I always use NULL in non-C++11 code. I find it much more expressive than 0. It is a widely spread use, from my experience, and it is not error prone in any way.

Comment: W@DavidRodriguez-dribeas  Why not NULL?

Comment: @DanielDaranas: I had a coworker in the past doing `#undef NULL` then `#define NULL (void*)"Learn to use 0"` in a commonly used header. I am not sure whether that is really legal in the language, but it messed us for a few hours :)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Of course this kind of abomination is bound to create trouble. There are people out there defining NULL, TRUE, FALSE, INT, etc. I'd revoke their C++ programming licenses :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't allocated the variable *graph* it might be NULL or just a dangling pointer.

Comment: `std::vector< std::vector<Rect> *> *graph= NULL` in declaration?

Comment: Use the solution of  David Rodríguez :)